# Repeat animation from the beginning every time the element comes into view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, framer-motion

I have created an animation that takes a couple of seconds to play. The animation should only run when the element is in view, so I've used `whileInView`. This works correctly, but when I scroll down (so the element is out of view), the animation seems to run backwards, because when I scroll up again, I can see that the animation does not start from the beginning but from the point that it reached when it ran backwards and when the element came into view again. I want the animation to run from the beginning instead.

I've created a small sandbox to demonstrate the issue:

https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-cache-mk2dq2?file=/src/App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: "1000px" }}>
      <motion.div
        id="box"
        initial={{ x: 0 }}
        whileInView={{ x: 300 }}
        transition={{ duration: 5, ease: "linear" }}
      >
        <p>
          The box should be moving now. Scroll down and then up again. The
          animation will not instantly reset but run backwards.
        </p>
      </motion.div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When you open the sandbox, the blue box will move. The animation takes 5 seconds. Scroll down and then up again (within five seconds). The animation will run from some point but not from the start.

How can I make the animation run from the start whenever the element comes into view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I used `useInView` to track when the div was scrolled past with `useEffect` to be called when this changed. [useInView reference](https://www.framer.com/motion/use-in-view/)
- When its in view it runs your animation & when out of view does a quick reverse animation (maybe this second part can be done better but it works).
- I also used `useAnimate` instead of the div definitions [see more about useAnimate here](https://www.framer.com/motion/use-animate/).
- I edited the App.js on your codesandbox but don't have an account to save and share a link. If you paste the below code in your sandbox's App.js it should give you what you are after

```
import "./styles.css";
import { motion, useInView, useAnimate  } from "framer-motion";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [scope, animate] = useAnimate()
  const motionDiv = useRef(null)
  const isInView = useInView(motionDiv)


  useEffect(()=>{
    if(isInView){
      animate("div", { x: 300 }, { duration:5, ease: "linear" })
    }else{
      animate("div", { x: 0 }, { duration:0 })
    }
  },[isInView, animate])

  return (
    <div ref={scope}  style={{ height: "1000px" }} >
    <div ref={motionDiv}>
      <motion.div
        id="box"
      >
        <p>
          The box should be moving now. Scroll down and then up again. The
          animation will not instantly reset but run backwards.
        </p>
      </motion.div>
    </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This answers the question so I will mark it as accepted. With your help I found a simpler solution that only requires two small edits (see my own answer).

Comment: @MichelKrämer, thanks. I really like your new solution, it is so much simpler! Happy to hear I gave you a (very small) bit of help to get there.

Answer (score 1):

p7dxb's answer gave me an idea. I found a very simple solution. You just have to set different transition values for `initial` and `whileInView`. Use a duration of 0 seconds for `initial`:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: "1000px" }}>
      <motion.div
        id="box"
        initial={{ x: 0, transition: { duration: 0 } }}
        whileInView={{ x: 300, transition: { duration: 5, ease: "linear" } }}
      >
        <p>
          The box should be moving now. Scroll down and then up again. The
          animation will not instantly reset but run backwards.
        </p>
      </motion.div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's the new sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-elgamal-p49wdq